# How to Call all of the XIB/NIB files properties?

Tags: iphone

I created a TabBarController application for the iPhone that has a mainView.xib with a tabBar, Two tabBar buttons, and two additional views. The additional views have a UIMapkit and a UITableView. What I want to do is in the tableview, I want to invoke the UIMapKit view when ever a user tabs on a row.

What I did:

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
MapViewController *NView = [[MapViewController alloc] 
                            initWithNibName:nil 
                            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self presentModalViewController:NView animated:YES];
```

}

Which creates an action for the rows. My problem is that it only shows the UIMapKit and not the tabBarController.

The TabBarController is in the mainWindow.

Is there some code that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to switch to the tab with the map, the methods/properties [`selectedViewController` or `selectedIndex` of UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController) should help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it to work: 
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

Comment: You're welcome :) But please look at @Mike's answer as well - he might be as well correct concerning the design of your app

Answer (score 0):

By your tags, I assume you're on iPhone and not iPad.  On iPhone, a modal view occupies the entire screen, covering tab bars, etc.  This is by design and cannot be changed.
So you need to do as @adubr said and set the selected index of your TabBarController.  But you also need to get the row index from your table view to the map (presumably the map is displayed differently based on which table row you tap.)  So I don;t think a tab bar is really what you want here.
It seems like you need a UINavigationController and then the tableViewController can just create an NView instance and push it onto the nav con stack.